pdf-tools and synctex do not work with \input{} latex comment
I am on Emacs 29.1. I'm a longtime user of auctex, synctex and pdf-tools. My config file contains.
;; Use emacs' pdf-tools to open PDF files:
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "PDF Tools"))
      TeX-source-correlate-start-server t)

;; use synctex for click on pdf to jump to that point in tex file, and vice versa:
(setq TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
(setq TeX-source-correlate-method 'synctex)

I'm having the following problem:  when I have all the latex source code in the current buffer I can correctly do forward and inverse search integration with the pdf file opened into the pdf-tools viewer. Suppose now that in the latex document I have
\input{foo/boo.tex}

In this case If I go on the pdf on line contained into boo.tex and I click on mouse it doesn't take me to boo.tex. The functionality works only if I manually open foo/boo.tex in a new buffer. The strange thing is that all this worked before moving from Emacs 28 to 29.1

I don't use pdf-tools, but in your boo.tex, do you have the local variables set properly, so something like this: %%% Local Variables: %%% mode: LaTeX %%% TeX-master: "../main-file.tex" %%% End: ?
